# Depended initializatoin list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm kind of new to C++ and encountered this desgin problem.

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class Dependee
{
public:
    // Constructors
    initialize();
};

class Depender
{
public:
    Depender(Dependee dependee);
    // Other constructors and stuff
};

class World
{
public:
    World();
private:
    Dependee dependee_;
    Depender depender_;
};
```

Now, depender depends on dependee for construction. But dependee not only has to be constructed prior to depender's construction, but also initialized using initialize().

There are several ways to solve this, the two I am considering is a static method inside the World class

```
static Dependee initDependee()
{
    Dependee dependee();
    if(!dependee.initialize())
    {
        throw SomeException();
    }

    return dependee;
}
```

and then doing:

```
World::World():
dependee_(initDependee()),
depender_(dependee_)
{}
```

or just initializing both using the default constructors, and doing the rest of the work in World's constructor

```
World::World() :
dependee_(),
depender_()
{
    Dependee dependee();
    dependee.initialize();

    dependee_ = dependee;

    Depender depender(dependee);

    depender_ = depender;
}
```

Obvoiusly I am open to any other solution, but consider that Dependee comes from an outside library.

PS: Is there are any good books on proper C++ design and coding conventions that you would recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to `initialize()` `Dependee` when you construct it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Where, in the initialization list? I'm not sure I can do that. VS is yealling at me that '.' ilegal in base/member initializer list.

Comment: You could call `initialize()` in the body of the `Dependee` constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, probably had to mention it, but dependee has to be initialized before depender can be constracted with it. I can initialize dependee in the body, but that means that depender has already been constructed (just like in my second option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-phase initialization generally is ill-advised. C++ has constructors! However, taken that it comes from third-party library and there is nothing you can do about it, I would certainly not recommend using default constructor for your Depender. Constructors were invented (among other things, of course) to preserve class invariants.

The problem with your static initializer is, of course, a copy-construction of your Dependee. Now, do you need a COPY of your dependee in your depender class? Or would a pointer do? Obviously, if it is pointer, you can simply use unique_ptr. Issues with that? Of course, dynamic allocation, which is not always preferred.

So how would you solve this dilemma? I would suggest a wrapper. Something like this:

```
template <class WRAPPEE> struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper() { wrappee.initialize(); }
    WRAPPEE& operator() { return wrappee; } // Add const version as well
private:
    WRAPPEE wrappee;
};

typedef Wrapper<Dependee> dependee_t;
dependee_t dependee;
....
depender(dependee);
```

This should work reasonable well.

Comment: I think that this is (almost) exactly what I'll do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are spawning a lot of copies either way. I would do it with shared pointers unless you really *need* to store separate copies of `Dependee` in `World` and `Depender`.

```
class Dependee
{
public:
    // Constructors
    initialize();
};

class Depender
{
public:
    Depender(shared_ptr<Dependee> dependee);
    // Other constructors and stuff
};

class World
{
public:
    World() : dependee_(new Dependee())
    {
        dependee_.initialize();
        depender_.reset(new Depender(dependee_));
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<Dependee> dependee_;
    shared_ptr<Depender> depender_;
};
```

This way you only construct and store 1 copy of every object.

Comment: This might be the most technically correct answer, but I don't like using sharet_ptrs unless I really really have to. Much obliged though for the answer!